# I am trying to launch firefox in selenium 3.0.1 using TestNG, but I am not able to do it. I have used setProperty also

Tags: java, selenium, testng-eclipse

```
package TestNG;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.sql.Driver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class TestNGClass {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    @FindBy(id="Email")
    private WebElement gmailUserName;

    @FindBy(id="Passwd")
    private WebElement gmailPwd;

    @FindBy(id="SignIn")
    private WebElement logInbtn;

  @Test
  public void gmailLogin() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.geko.driver","C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      gmailUserName.clear();
      gmailUserName.sendKeys("hkj@gmail.com");

      gmailPwd.clear();
      gmailPwd.sendKeys("password");

      logInbtn.click();
  }
  @BeforeTest
  public void launchapp() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.geko.driver","C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
      driver.close();
  }
}
```

**Error.**

```
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:37)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:277)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
    at TestNG.TestNGClass.<init>(TestNGClass.java:17)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `webdriver.gecko.driver`.